# Find the Second largest number of a nested list programme

Tags: python, list

Given the names and grades for each student in a Physics class of **N** students, store them in a nested list and print the name(s) of any student(s) having the second lowest grade.

**Note**: If there are multiple students with the same grade, order their names alphabetically and print each name on a new line.

**Input**

```
  students = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]]
```

Below is my code for the above question :-

```
marks = sorted([student[i][1] for i in range(len(student))], reverse = True)

for num in range(1,len(marks)):
    if marks[num] < marks[0]:
        if marks[num+1] < marks[num]:
            temp = marks[num+1]
            break
    else:
        continue
second_top = [student[i] for i in range(len(student)) if student[i][1] == temp]

topper = sorted([k for k,l in second_top])

for i in range(len(topper)):
    print(topper[i])
```

**Ouptut**

```
Berry
Harry
```

Is there a way to improve this code. I'm a new to Python started practising on Hacker rank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I would sort the grades y ascending order:

```
>>> students = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]]
>>> grades = sorted(set(g for _, g in students))
>>> grades
[37.2, 37.21, 39, 41]
```

The line `set(g for _, g in students)` extract the grades and remove the duplicates (`set`).

Then take the second element of the list, which is the second lowest grade:

```
>>> second_lowest_grade = grades[1]
>>> second_lowest_grade
37.21
```

And then loop on ordered names (alpabetically) for students having the second lowest grade:

```
>>> for name in sorted(n for n, g in students if g == second_lowest_grade):
...     print(name)
... 
Berry
Harry
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, which accounts for ex-aequos too:

```
students = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Joe', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]]

scores = sorted(set([s[1] for s in students]))

students_by_score = {score: [student for student in students if student[1] == score] for score in scores}

second_bests = students_by_score[scores[1]]  # or whichever rank you want

print(second_bests)
```

Result:

```
[['Berry', 37.21], ['Harry', 37.21]]
```

Comment: The is incorrect answer. because if there are multiple lowest values, the ranked[1][1] <> second lowest value.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll try and fix that differently than with the sad for loop of the approved answer.

Comment: Done ... Thanks for noticing that :)

Answer (score 2):

you could use a list comprehension with [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import groupby, islice

s = [i[0]  for e in islice((list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(students), key=lambda x: x[1])), 1, 2) for i in e]

print(*s, sep='\n')
```

output:

```
Berry
Harry
```

---

another approach will be to store your data in a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) where the key will be the grade and the values will be a list with all the students that have the grade specified by the key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

grade_student = defaultdict(list)
for student, grade in students:
    grade_student[grade].append(student)

# second lowest grade   
second_grade = sorted(grade_student.keys())[1]

# order the names alphabetically and print each name on a new line
print(*sorted(grade_student[second_grade]), sep='\n')
```

output:

```
Berry
Harry
```

Answer (score 0):

A newbie way to do it: Clears all the tests!!!

```
listb=[] (creating an empty list)
n=int(input()) (number of items in list)

for i in range(n): (loop initiated for creating a list A with names)
    lista=[]
    name = input()
    lista.append(name)

    for j in range (1): (loop for entering the score in list a, and making list b)
        score = float(input())
        lista.append(score)
        listb.append(lista)

listc=sorted(listb, key=lambda i: i[1]) (sort the list)
minx=min(listc, key=lambda i: i[1]) (taking minimum value)
second_minimum_score = max(listc, key=lambda i: i[1]>minx[1]) (extracting second minimum value)
my_value=second_minimum_score[1]
chaapo=[] (this list will contain our answer)
for i in range(len(listc)):
    if listc[i][1]==my_value:
      chaapo.append(listc[i][0])
    
y=sorted(chaapo)

for i in range (len(y)): (loop for printing, if there are multiple names)
    print(y[i])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).